# The Language does not change in the ASP.NET Core Web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1, asp.net-core-localization

I follow the [Globalization and localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) and [Building simple multilingual ASP.NET Core website](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/codefusion/archive/2016/10/13/building-simple-multilingual-asp-net-core-website.aspx) tutorials to add a language switch for my application.

So, I created a partial view

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home"
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path"
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        @Localizer["Language:"] 
        <select name="culture"
                onchange="this.form.submit();"
                asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems"></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Added in the footer of the `_Layout` the

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_SelectLanguagePartial")
</div>
```

and configure the Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("es"),
        new CultureInfo("en")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "es", uiCulture: "es");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;    

});
```

I added a `Resources` folder and in it the

```
Views.Home.Index.es.resx
Views.Home.Index.en.resx
Views.Shared._Layout.es.resx
Views.Shared._Layout.en.resx
```

I also did `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies`

When I load the Home View I have the Spanish option selected. But when I try to select "English" it loads, but rolls-back the Spanish version, so I can't finally see my content in English. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you add javascript to make the language selector postback?

```
(function () {
$("#selectLanguage select").change(function () {
    $(this).parent().submit();
});
}());
```

Did you wire up therequest localization middleware in Configure?

```
var locOptions= app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

Did you add a method in HomeController like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
    );

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: I had the first two options missing. The first one was't mentionned in the tutorial, the second one I did't read properly ! Thanks a lot ! The third would thow an exception, not the case :)

Comment: There is just a problem with the `DisplayAttribute` localization... surely is an  other story, but it seems that is not working yet...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833661/asp-net-core-displayattribute-localization

Comment: My problem was once another one :) I used custom @Html.DisplayShortNameFor(), so, the proposed solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234670/asp-net-core-shortname-in-the-display-attribute-dataannotations does not take into account the internationalization

Comment: The "standard" `DisplayNameFor` worked without additional stuff

Answer (score 11):

Add an additional answer for those who did not make it work even if you have updated your code with Joe Auddette's answer.

The `CookieOptions` blocked me a long time to make things work:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions
        {
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
            IsEssential = true,  //critical settings to apply new culture
            Path = "/",
            HttpOnly = false,
        }
    );

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

`IsEssential` has following comments in source code:

> Indicates if this cookie is essential for the application to function
>   correctly. If true then consent policy checks may be bypassed. The
>   default value is false.

and the `consent policy` is set in `startup.cs`

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies 
    // is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```