DateTIme.ToString returns different results in localhost and Azure
We have an ASP.NET Core 8 website:

We have set the culture to da-DK.
In C# code inside Startup it shows that the TimeSeparator is ':' and DateSeperator is '-'.
In an MVC view using System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture it shows that the TimeSeparator is '.' and DateSeperator is '.'.

If I make a DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm") it will return a string of the form dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm in the MVC view but dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm in non-Razor C# code elsewhere in the project.
Code is .net 8 and this bug suddenly appeared a few days ago.
This is the code I use in my view to see what values are actually passed as the culture and a ToString()
@using System.Threading

<div style="display:none;">
    <p>@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name</p>
    <p>@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator</p>
    <p>@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator</p>
    <p>@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")</p>
</div>

This is the result I get in Azure:
<div style="display:none;">
    <p>da-DK</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>09-11-2024 23.20</p>
</div>

This is the result I get in Localhost
<div style="display:none;">
    <p>da-DK</p>
    <p>:</p>
    <p>-</p>
    <p>09-11-2024 23:44</p>
</div>

I have this in my Startup.cs:
      var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
      cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = ":";
      cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
      var supportedCultures = new CultureInfo[] { cultureInfo };
    
      app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
      {
          DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCultures[0]),
          SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
          SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
      });

If I do the same in my backend it returns the expected result dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm.
I don't think I can do much better than this, I can't explain it.
The whole thing started 2 days after the latest upload.
I tried to test the RequestCulture this was the result I got in Azure(LocalHost returned as expected ):
@{
var requestCulture= HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Features.Get<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.Culture;
}

<div style="display:none;">
    <p>da-DK</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>10-11-2024 00.42</p>
    <p>da-DK</p>
    <p>:</p>
    <p>-</p>
</div>

Azure Web app is running this plan:


It isn't possible for DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm") to return a string containing dots instead of dashes because that's not how .NET's DateTime formatting works - (whereas the '/' char does have varying output results). Please provide more context, and ideally a block of code we can run ourselves that reproduces the issue.

Also, the "MVC view" is still rendered "in the backend" - there is no front-end here. Unless you're using Blazor? Your post doesn't mention it, so I assumed you aren't.

I am not using blazor, I have tried adding some more code. It makes no sense to me.

You said this is hosted/running in Azure - please specify if this is in Azure App Service (if so, what AppServicePlan tier are you using?) - or in an Azure VM - or something else?

What happens if you compare HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.Culture.DateTimeFormat with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat?`

I tested the Request culture as you asked for and added the host plan. It is very odd that the cultures are the same but the separators are not.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549533/net-core-mvc-requestlocalization-ignoring-defaultrequestculture

@HansPassant I tried that but now it returns separators as . in all cases which is wrong, why does it do that ?

@Nicolaijee The only way to find out for sure is to attach a debugger and set a breakpoint within .NET's CultureInfo API surface and see what callers are changing options. BTW, please check the CultureInfo.IsReadOnly property: if it's false then see what happens if you change your code to use CultureInfo danish = CultureInfo.ReadOnly( new CultureInfo("da-DK") ) in your Startup class.

@Dai I tried that, but still happens.
I have sort of given up on this.
I changed everything so I just use manual formatting.
Will close the topic.

@Nicolaijee "I tried that, but still happens" - was the breakpoint hit or not? Did you have symbols loaded for the CLR assemblies?

I did and I could not find anything hitting those breakpoints.
I upgraded it to .net 9 and set the things in my reply and that helped

I managed to solve this by creating this property
 private CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get
        {
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
            cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
            cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
            cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
            cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = ":";
            cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
            cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm";
            return CultureInfo.ReadOnly(cultureInfo);
        }
    }

In my configureservices I added this code:
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = Culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = Culture;
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = Culture;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = Culture;

In my configure method I added these lines of code:
 var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
 {
     DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(Culture),
     SupportedCultures = new[] { Culture },
     SupportedUICultures = new[] { Culture }
 };

 app.UseRequestLocalization(options);

